# Show that $\{\sin(nx) \; \mid \; n \in N\}$ is not equicontinuous at $x=1$

Tags: uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

> Show that $\{\sin(nx) \; \mid \; n \in N\}$ is not equicontinuous at
>   $x=1$

I have not fully grasped the concept of equicontinuity and uniform equicontinuity. If someone can solve this properly it will really help me get more comfortable with it

$H\subset C(X)$ is equicontinuous at $ x_0$ if $\forall \epsilon>0 \; \exists \delta(x,\epsilon)\in N \ni d(x,x_0)<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)- f(x_0)|< \epsilon \; \forall f\in C(X)$

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write down the definition of equicontinuous? Can you try proving it directly?

Comment: @CalvinLin I really don't have idea, I have added the definition. It will help me a lot if you could answer it. I usually don't post without answers but I am going blank on this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\{ \sin {nx} \}$ is equicontinuous.
Then, for $ \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, $\exists \delta >0 $ such that if $d( x, x_0 ) < \delta$, we have $\sin nx - \sin n < \frac{1}{2}$.

How do we get a contradiction? If you get stuck, look at the following hints.

> Take $n$ large enough so that $ n \delta >> 2\pi$.

$ $

> Show that there exists $x_1, x_2 \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ such that $ \sin nx_1 = 1, \sin nx_2 = -1$.

$ $

> Why does this lead to a contradiction?